# Materialize active tab not working in Modal

Tags: html, css, tabs, materialize

The active tab doesn't show an underline when in a Modal even though I have given one of the tabs a `class` of `active`. However, once I click on one of the tabs it starts working. What is the issue?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndugc1ma/).

And here is the spot where I'm giving the element the proper `class` name:

```
...
<a class="active" href="#test1">Test 1</a>
...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same thing happens when you init tabs on a hide div...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underline will show if you initialize the tabs using the `ready` option of the Modal window.

Something like this:

```
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
    ready: function () {
        $('ul.tabs').tabs();
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/powxw392/

If you want a bit of an animation when you pop the modal window, place the tabs initialization outside of the modal function and add a click event like so:

```
$('ul.tabs').tabs();
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
    ready: function () {
        $('#firstTab').click();
    }
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qj0r84dr/

Both options will allow you to retain the animation of the underline moving from tab to tab.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't see the underline is because there is no underline.
The line you are seeing is a div with a class of `indicator` which moves programatically to which ever tab is selected.

The way I see it, you can either **override the indicator with your own CSS**:

```
.tabs .indicator { display: none; }
.tabs .tab a.active { border-bottom: 2px solid #f6b2b5; }
```

The problem here is that you lose the animation.

You can also **set the indicator's position manually**:

```
 $('#modal1').find('.indicator').attr('style', 'right: 415.333px; left: 0px;');
```

The problem with this one is that it's a little dirty.

[Updated fiddle (with the second choice).](https://jsfiddle.net/ndugc1ma/1/)